# What is the purpose of the `Retail price` field in the django oscar dashboard?

Tags: django, django-oscar

[image: django-oscar dashboard stock and pricing fields]

I've attempted to input a value for the `Retail price` field in the django oscar dashboard in both versions 1.6 and 2.0
for a dummy product, however, no visible changes were observed in the product detail pages, nor does checking out reflect
the retail price. I went through the source code a bit, and I found some comments indicating that retail price, along with
some other items will be depracated in django oscar 2.1.  Does this mean that the `Retail price` field in the dashboard
is not meant to be used by new projects, and is simply there for those who have used this in the past?

Comment: The field isn't used, and is deprecated and scheduled for removal: https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/60c1241e756f2b1a01caaa2f47b91309bec705ea/src/oscar/apps/partner/abstract_models.py#L122

Comment: Thanks.  I'll avoid doing anything using the field.